# How to get cv2.imshow() to show frames from a list?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save the last 50 frames from my webcam into a list and then play those frames back.  When I try to display the frame the display window shows gray and says it is unresponsive.  If I show the frame in the while loop it displays but if i try to show the frames from the list i saved them in the above issue occurs.  This is the code I am running.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
image_list = []
count = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    image_list.append(frame)

    #Display the resulting frame
    #cv2.imshow('frame',frame)   <---  this will show me my live frame by frame capture

    if count >= 50:
        break

    count += 1

# When everything is done, release the capture
cap.release()

for image in image_list:  
    cv2.imshow("frame", image)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: I suspect `sleep(1)` to completely freeze your application, thus the unresponsive display window. Try using `cv2.waitKey(1000)` instead. See the doc on [`waitKey`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) for further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not use a proper UI Framerwork like tkinter or Qt you have to call

```
cv2.waitKey(500)
```

periodically as it is the only way for the Highgui component of OpenCv to process events (and update the display). Otherwise the highgui just "hangs up".

```
for image in image_list:  
    cv2.imshow("frame", image)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
```

Excerpt from the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey):

> Note
>
> This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle
>   events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event
>   processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes
>   care of event processing.